# Duplex Data Preparation using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with data and I need to prepare the data rows for duplex printing using defined fields and variables.

I have created set of temp tables as below:

**#OriginalData**:

```
Code Department Brand   PageNumber SequenceNo Reverse
-----------------------------------------------------
101  201        LG      1          1          0
102  201        Samsung 1          2          0
105  203        Apple   1          3          0
106  203        Nokia   1          4          0
103  202        Sony    2          5          0
104  202        Sony    2          6          0
107  203        TCL     2          7          0
108  203        BenQ    2          8          0
```

**#Required Data**:

```
Code Department Brand   PageNumber SequenceNo Reverse
-----------------------------------------------------
101  201        LG      1          1          0
102  201        Samsung 1          2          0
105  203        Apple   1          3          0
106  203        Nokia   1          4          0

101  201        LG      1          5          1 - Required
102  201        Samsung 1          6          1 - Required
105  203        Apple   1          7          1 - Required
106  203        Nokia   1          8          1 - Required

103  202        Sony    2          9           0
104  202        Sony    2          10          0
107  203        TCL     2          11          0
108  203        BenQ    2          12          0 

103  202        Sony    2          13          1 - Required
104  202        Sony    2          14          1 - Required
107  203        TCL     2          15          1 - Required
108  203        BenQ    2          16          1 - Required
```

I need the data as per the second table. I am planning to use the original data for the front of the page and use data from RequireDupexData table for back of the page.

Is there a way to change the SequenceNo order using SQL? so when combined with Original data they can be printed correctly in terms of duplex printing.

Notes:

1. Example 2 data rows per page
2. Example 2 columns per page
3. The data is passed to an application that creates artwork
4. Same data rows are used for the back of the page hence why the duplicated tables.

[image]

[image]

**Update: Modified my required data to make more sense. In my example I have considered 2 columns and 2 rows but these can change depending on the page/template design. Hence I believe columns or rows or both must be considered in order to reorder the SequenceNo for required data.**

Comment: Does this work - select [Code], [Department], [Brand],  [PageNumber], [SequenceNo], 
       case when [PageNumber] = 1 THEN [SequenceNo] + 2 ELSE [SequenceNo] - 2 AS [ReverseSequenceNo], 
    [Reverse]
   from your_table

Comment: The numbers are the original "rotated" by two, with the sequence based on 0. You can use `1+(SequenceNo +1)%4)`

Comment: That is a sample data. There could be more than 4 records and number of columns and rows in the page can change.

Comment: @Sam, that only works for the example. I think i need to write a formula that can correctly set the SequenceNo based on the columns or rows in the page.

Comment: @ThiruKallem I see number of rows and columns have changed in the second screenshot. lets say, if there are 110 rows do you have 11 rows by 11 columns? what is the criteria here to decide number columns and rows based on data in lay man terms (not in programming language)

Comment: Instead of having a whole new table, could you change the 'Reverse' column to hold the Reverse Sequence Number? It sounds like that's the only difference between the two tables.

Comment: @sam, No,  the columns and rows are fixed on a page, imagine you have an A4 page and you can have above cells in a size of A6 (i.e. First screenshot) which means you can have 4 records on a page. If there are 20 rows then that will be printed on 5 pages.

Comment: I will need to create another 20 rows of same data to print on the back of the the page which I am calling DuplexData but the DuplexData must be in an order so when printed the rows in the cells in the front and back of the page are for the same data row. Hence I need to reorder the SequenceNo in the duplex data using the either fixed Columns or fixed Rows or both.

Comment: Thiru Kallem - Column Count = MAX(SequenceNo) WHERE Page=1  --> RowCount = MAX(SequenceNo) / Column Count <-- Only works if pages do not contain gaps. If there are gaps then guidance is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work to reverse your sequence number

```
--drop table #temp
create table #temp(
seq int,
)
insert into #temp
values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14)

declare @third int;
set @third = ceiling((select count(seq)/3.0 from #temp))
select @third

select seq 
, case when seq <= @third
then seq + 2*@third
when seq <= 2*@third
then seq
when seq > 2*@third
then seq - 2*@third
end as rseq
from #temp 
order by seq asc
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I am afraid that didn't work please see the screenshot. I will need the second table data for back of the page. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IopZ.png